# Cursor offset after scaling Highstock chart

Tags: highcharts

We are using Highstock to display our data.

The project has pre-existing code that uses CSS transform to make the chart larger or smaller e.g. `transform: scale(0.7)`

The problem is, this CSS transform causes the cursor to be offset when using the navigator bar and hovering over data points.

The requirements at the minute mean I cannot take out the transform to use the inbuilt `Chart.setSize()` function.

Here is the attempt so far: http://jsfiddle.net/c8bfwhg0/30/

NOTE: I tried getting the post-transform height and width and applying `Chart.setSize()` with those values, but the problem persists.

Comment: This is bug in the Highcharts lib: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/2405

Comment: Found this an hour after I posted it, kzoon's work around fixed the problem for the tooltip and navigator bar. Here's my [example with the workaround in place](http://jsfiddle.net/c8bfwhg0/50/)